# How to know if all the boxes are checked and return unchecked boxes

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am new in the ERP programming environment and I work on `Odoo 8`. I have a problem I cannot solve: I create a view component as a set of documents to provide for an administrative record with the type `boolean check box`es and I want that the record I view tells me if the folder is complete or not, and the boxes that are not checked.

I hope I stay clear in the exhibition of my problem and I know you will kindly offer me other solutions. the problem is simple and I want to know if a file is complete or not.

My test is:

```
def get_etat_dossier(self,cr,uid,ids,args,fields,casier_judiciare,context=None):
        res = {}
        for rec in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):

            if rec.casier_judiciare==True: # test field if = true 


        return {'value':{'etat_dos':'complet'}}   


_columns= {  
       'casier_judiciare' : fields.boolean('Casier Judiciaire'),
       'cnas' : fields.boolean('CNAS'),
       'casnos' : fields.boolean('CASNOS'),
       'bilan_finance' : fields.boolean('Bilan Financier'),
       'reference_pro' : fields.boolean('Réferences Professionnelles'),
       'certificat_qual' : fields.boolean('Certificat de qualification'),
       'num_iden_fiscale' : fields.boolean('N° Fiscale'),
       'statut_entre' : fields.selection([('eurl','EURL'),('sarl','SARL')],'Statut Entreprise'),
       # field change automaticaly
       'etat_dos': fields.selection([('complet','Dossier Complet'),
                                     ('manquant','Dossier Manquant')],
                                     'Etat De Dossier'),
}
```

This is a description of my problem:
[image: Highlighted Issue]

Comment: What do you mean by "if the folder is complete"? How do you define that?

Comment: if I tick all the boxes.  
Fields represented the pieces of an administrative file

Comment: I try this solution of one combo : 'def get_etat_dossier(self,cr,uid,ids,args,fields,context=None):
  res = {}
  for rec in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
   t1='Dossier Complet'
   t2='Dossier Manquant'
   if rec.casier_judiciare==True:
    res[rec.id] = t1
  res[rec.id] = t2
    
  return res'   But i dont know how fonction return Strinr

Comment: Edit your question to add the code there. It's nearly impossible to read in a comment, without any formatting or line breaks...

Comment: Hello @Smith Please don't post duplicates of your question. if someone hasn't answered it's likely that they don't understand your question because it's not clear enough to them or they simply don't know. Also try to be as clear as possible when posting :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Chage selection field automaticaly in odoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083117/how-to-chage-selection-field-automaticaly-in-odoo)