# How to Change selection field automatically in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm working on Odoo 8. I have a view that contains a set of combo-box type fields and a selection field. I want to make a test on the combo-box fields and if there are all checked then the selection field value should change. Here is what i have so far:

```
def get_etat_dossier(self,cr,uid,ids,args,fields,context=None):
    res = {}
    for rec in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):

        if rec.casier_judiciare==True: # test field if = true 
            res[rec.id]= 02 # field etat_dos type selection = Dossier Complet
        else:
            res[rec.id] = 01

    return res


_columns= {

   'casier_judiciare' : fields.boolean('Casier Judiciaire'), #  field to test 

   'reference_pro' : fields.boolean('Réferences Professionnelles'),
   'certificat_qual' : fields.boolean('Certificat de qualification'),
   'extrait_role' : fields.boolean('Extrait de Role'),
   'statut_entre' : fields.selection([('eurl','EURL'),('sarl','SARL')],'Statut Entreprise'),
   'etat_dos': fields.selection([('complet','Dossier Complet'),('manquant','Dossier Manquant')],'Etat De Dossier'), # field ho change after test 
}
```

[image]

Here is the code for my view

```
<group col='4' name="doss_grp" string="Dossier de Soumission" colspan="4" >       <field name="casier_judiciare"/> 
    <field name="certificat_qual"/> 
    <field name="extrait_role"/> 
    <field name="reference_pro"/> 
    <field name="statut_entre" style="width:20%%"/> 
    <field name="etat_dos"/> 
</group>
```

Comment: You have to show us the code for you view...if i understand you properly you want to change the values of a selection field if a combo box (check-box) field is checked or not

Comment: Hi @danidee it is what i want  my view is : '<group col='4' name="doss_grp" string="Dossier de Soumission" colspan="4" > 
                            
                            <field name="casier_judiciare"/>   
                            <field name="certificat_qual"/>
                            <field name="extrait_role"/>
                            <field name="reference_pro"/>
                             <field name="statut_entre" style="width:20%%"/>
                            <field name="etat_dos"/>
                        </group>'

Comment: is it all the check-box fields you want to check or just a specific one?...also next time paste your code in the question not as a comment it's very hard to read like that

Comment: Hi danidee I have update my question and i want if one box are checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `onchange` attribute to the `casier_judiciare` field and then pass all the other fields you want to check as arguments to the method like this

```
<group col='4' name="doss_grp" string="Dossier de Soumission" colspan="4" >
    <field name="casier_judiciare" on_change="onchange_casier_judiciare(casier_judiciare, certificat_qual, extrait_role, reference_pro)"/> 
    <field name="certificat_qual"/> 
    <field name="extrait_role"/> 
    <field name="reference_pro"/> 
    <field name="statut_entre" style="width:20%%"/> 
    <field name="etat_dos"/> 
</group>
```

In your model file define the method like this and use an if statement to check if they're all True (That means they have all been checked), if so then you can return a dictionary with any value you want for the selection field, in this case `etat_dos` will change to `Dossier Complet`

```
def onchange_casier_judiciare(self, cr, uid, ids, casier_judiciare, certificat_qual, extrait_role, reference_pro, context=None):
    if casier_judiciare and certificat_qual and extrait_role and reference_pro: # if they're all True (that means they're all checked):
        values = {'value': {'etat_dos': 'complet'}} #set the value of etat_dos field

        return values
```

Note that the `onchange` is only triggered on the `casier_judiciare` field but you can also set `onchange` on other fields and it should work just fine